# Azure IoT SDK - check if device has been enrolled already

Tags: c, azure, azure-iot-hub, provisioning, azure-iot-sdk

I am using the Azure IoT C SDK on my device.

My application does the provisioning as per sample code `prov_dev_client_ll_sample.c` , but after that, also handles the communication to its twin on the cloud etc. via MQTT as per sample code `iothub_client_device_twin_and_methods_sample.c` .

Ideally, I guess the provisioning logic should only be executed the very first time the device boots up and enrolls itself on the portal, and not every time it boots up.

Is there a way / function to check if the device has already been enrolled on the portal before executing the provisioning logic?

I guess it doesn't do much harm executing the provisioning logic anyways, as it figures out that the device is already enrolled on the portal anyways?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [REST API - Device Registration Status Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/runtimeregistration/deviceregistrationstatuslookup) to obtain a device registration status.

The following is an example of the POST request for a *device10* registration status in the underlying IoT Hub of the IoT Central App (*iotcScopeId = 0ne11111111*):

request POST:

```
  https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/0ne11111111/registrations/device10?api-version=2019-03-31
```

header:

```
  Authorization: sas
```

where the *sas* token can be generated by the following function (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342491/how-do-we-connect-android-ios-app-to-azure-iot-central-and-send-telemetry-data)):

```
 string sas = SharedAccessSignatureBuilder.GetSASToken($"{iotcScopeId}/registrations/{deviceId}", deviceKey, "registration");
```

payload:

```
 {
   "registrationId":"device10"
 }
```

response:

```
{
    "registrationId":"device10",
    "createdDateTimeUtc":"2020-06-20T12:38:45.451863Z",
    "assignedHub":"iotc-xxxxxxx.azure-devices.net",
    "deviceId":"device10",
    "status":"assigned",
    "substatus":"initialAssignment",
    "lastUpdatedDateTimeUtc":"2020-06-20T12:38:45.6268772Z",
    "etag":"xxxxx"
}
```

in the case of not exist device, the response is:

```
 {
   "errorCode": 404202,
   "trackingId": "481a4060-37c1-40e2-8a23-d225e49781c6",
   "message": "Registration not found.",
   "timestampUtc": "2020-06-20T12:36:43.8782738Z"
 }
```