# Problems with creating HTTP request for creating device in azure iot hub using Device Provisoning service

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I read this article for creating device in azure iot hub but i have problems in creating sas token which return me HTTP 401 Unauthorized

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-control-access

This is my method of creating the sas token:

```
    private static String SCOPE_ID = "0ne0032AAD2";
    private static final String GLOBAL_ENDPOINT = "global.azure-devices-provisioning.net";
    private static final String SYMMETRIC_KEY = "symmetric key from hub";
    private static final String REGISTRATION_ID = "device1";
    public static HttpClient httpClient;
    private static int httpTimeoutInMilliseconds = 24000;**

      public static String generateSasToken() throws Exception {
            // Token will expire in one hour
            var expiry = Instant.now().getEpochSecond() + 3600;
    
            String stringToSign = URLEncoder.encode(GLOBAL_ENDPOINT, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + "\n" + expiry;
            byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(SYMMETRIC_KEY);
    
            Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "HmacSHA256");
            sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
            Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    
            String signature = new String(encoder.encode(
                sha256HMAC.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    
            String token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + URLEncoder.encode(GLOBAL_ENDPOINT, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    + "&sig=" + URLEncoder.encode(signature, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()) + "&se=" + expiry + "&skn=provisioningserviceowner";
                
            return token;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342491/how-do-we-connect-android-ios-app-to-azure-iot-central-and-send-telemetry-data) (Update-2) with a detail implementation (C#).
Basically the following inputs are for generating a sas_token:

- resourceUri = $"{scopeId}/registrations/{deviceId}"
- signingKey =  deviceKey
- policyName = "registration"

endpointAddressUri = $"https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/{scopeId}/registrations/{deviceId}/register?api-version=2019-03-31";

**Update:**

Note, that the pointed example has been implemented for *Azure IoT Central* configured by the following variables in the application settings:

- AzureIoTC_scopeId
- AzureIoTC_sasToken

In the case for registering the device(s) for *Azure IoT Hub* via the Azure Device Provisioning Service, we have to use the Enrollment Group, see the following:

- value of the Azure DPS **ID Scope**
- value of the Azure DPS group **Primary Key**

the following screen snippet shows my example:
[image]

The *deviceKey* is computed from the above *primary key* of the DPS Enrollment Group (group1) and from the specific *deviceId*.

The response of the azure function where is handled a device registration is the following (in this example the *deviceid=device10101*):

[image]

and finally, the following picture shows a registered device in the Azure Iot Hub:

[image]

Comment: i added an image but i can realize where is the wrong in the sas token, do you hava an idea

Comment: did you try to create the sas_token from the above parameters such as the *resourceUri*, *signingKey* and *policyName*?

Comment: I have updated my answer for details how to use it for creating a device in the Azure IoT Hub via the Azure DPS using the REST APIs. Note, that the Enrollment Group must be created in your DPS.

Comment: really thanks a i fixed it, the problem was in the sas token.Thanks for the answers it will be very helpfull for someone else :) Hava a nice day!