# DeviceClient error when it calls method open

Tags: android, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-central

I'm using this sample code for Android from [this page](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-java/blob/master/iot-hub/Samples/device/AndroidSample/things/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/iot/sdk/samples/androidsample/things/MainActivity.java).

Just replaced the content of *connstring* from line 29 with `"Hostname=<myHostname>.azureiotcentral.com;DeviceId=<myDevice>;SharedAccessKey=<myPrimaryKey>"`;

I'm using SAS Authentication.

The first error is when it tries to call `client.open()` (line 138).

It's giving me the following error each time when it's trying sending messages (line 122).

```
Connected to process 20170 on device '7.3_Foldable_API_30 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
    No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
I/TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.kttracking
W/System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf03da8e0, tid 20194
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
W/System.err: Exception while opening IoTHub connection: java.io.IOException: Could not open the connection
I/System.out: Shutting down...
I/System.out: Message Sent: "temperature":22.84, "humidity":48.31
W/System.err: Exception while sending event: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot send event from an IoT Hub client that is closed.
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf03f3ee0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf03f3ee0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf0738cf0) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf03f3af0, tid 20194
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fc01c000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
I/System.out: Message Sent: "temperature":20.74, "humidity":31.12
W/System.err: Exception while sending event: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot send event from an IoT Hub client that is closed.
I/System.out: Message Sent: "temperature":26.08, "humidity":43.27
W/System.err: Exception while sending event: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot send event from an IoT Hub client that is closed.
```

Comment: How did you get the connection string to the underlying IoT Hub of your IoT Central App?

Comment: At first I followed the next [manual](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.deviceclient.deviceclient?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_sdk_iot_device_DeviceClient_DeviceClient_java_lang_String_com_microsoft_azure_sdk_iot_device_IotHubClientProtocol_), asking with the following syntax, but then a friend told me that I have to use this [page](https://dpsgen.z8.web.core.windows.net/), that will generate the connstring.

The best I could get was `IoT Hub responded to message 32 with status OK_EMPTY`, but I didn't see any result in iotcentral.

Comment: I tried to use your connection string generator for iot central app for my working sample, but it returned an error. Have a look at my answer in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342491/how-do-we-connect-android-ios-app-to-azure-iot-central-and-send-telemetry-data

Answer (score 0):

What protocol are you using? Is that a MQTT? Also please check the version of the device client are you using.

Second thing that you can do is to try on a different device and see if the issue persists. at time certain devices  do exhibit issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I tried this [library](https://github.com/lucadruda/iotc-java-device-client). It works.

Comment: Mark this as answer to help others. Thanks