# Not able to provision IOT device under specific Device Template in Azure IoT Central

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Recently I saw that in IoT Central app if I create a new Device Template, we get a Interface id in the format like this "dtmi:iosIotCentralApp:DeviceTestTemplate21i;1". And if I use this for DeviceProvisioning function as cmid then I am getting below error in Azure function "Please follow the schema if you want to pass __iot:interfaces section under data. Format: '__iot:interfaces':{'CapabilityModelId': urn:companyname:template:templatename:version, 'CapabilityModel': 'The inline contents of interfaces and capability model.'}"

If I manually create cmid in format (urn:companyname:template:templatename:version) Device is provisioned but not assigned to the specific Device Template.

I am using below API for registration in an Azure function

PUT [https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/{idScope}/registrations/{registrationId}/register?api-version=2019-03-31](https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/%7BidScope%7D/registrations/%7BregistrationId%7D/register?api-version=2019-03-31)

Are there any changes in API for Device provisioning or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342491/how-do-we-connect-android-ios-app-to-azure-iot-central-and-send-telemetry-data).

The following is a DPS payload for passing the model id:

```
{
  "registrationId":"yourDeviceId",
  "payload": {
     "modelId": "yourDeviceTemplateModelId"
   }
}
```

See more details in the [IoT Plug and Play device developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-pnp/concepts-developer-guide-device?pivots=programming-language-csharp).

Comment: Thank you. In your code after passing {"modelId": "deviceTemplateModelId"} in json string I was able to assign device to particular Device Template

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark an answer, which it will help others.